# Can't figure out how to deserialize this JSON into C#

Tags: c#, json, json.net

I've tried several deserializers but can't figure out how to get an array of entries rather than a class for each entry.  Below is the json2csharp input and output.

```
[
  {
    "subdeviceGuid": "000781000030534e",
    "componentId": "all",
    "entries": {
      "1619701200000": {
        "min": 0.437,
        "max": 2.014,
        "mean": 0.751
      },
      "1619704800000": {
        "min": 0.526,
        "max": 2.089,
        "mean": 0.893
      },
      "1619708400000": {
        "min": -1.456,
        "max": -0.989,
        "mean": -1.328
      }
    }
  }
]
```

and the c# classes created by https://json2csharp.com/

```
// Root myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(myJsonResponse); 
    public class _1619701200000
    {
        public double min { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
        public double mean { get; set; }
    }

    public class _1619704800000
    {
        public double min { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
        public double mean { get; set; }
    }

    public class _1619708400000
    {
        public double min { get; set; }
        public double max { get; set; }
        public double mean { get; set; }
    }

    public class Entries
    {
        public _1619701200000 _1619701200000 { get; set; }
        public _1619704800000 _1619704800000 { get; set; }
        public _1619708400000 _1619708400000 { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string subdeviceGuid { get; set; }
        public string componentId { get; set; }
        public Entries entries { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: If you want an array of entries what are you expecting to happen with the long numbers that identify each entry? Are these moving to another property (perhaps EntryId?), are you discarding them?

Comment: That's a good point and question. they are unix time values and ideally, they really should be at the same level as the min/max/mean values.

Comment: You may want to reconsider your class structure. Classes… _1619701200000, _1619704800000 and _1619708400000 … all have the same structure. What happens if you get a new “number”? You would have to create a new “number” class with the “same” structure? Simplify this with “ONE” (1) Class called something like “numberedItem” and add an ID property that is the “class” name. Then you can add the items to a binding list or list.

Comment: I'm not following. could you make a small example of the classes?

Comment: Change the name of the first class `_1619701200000` to `EntryItem` or whatever you like. Then, add an `int` or `string` property called something like… `public int EntryID`. This value would be what your current class has as the class name. In the first example, `EntryID = 1619701200000`. Does that make sense?

Comment: yes, thanks.   @hans answer below is what I was looking for.  The dictionary makes most sense to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Auto-generated classes usually have issues with JSON structures that are best represented as dictionaries. Try these classes instead

```
public class Entry
{
    public double min { get; set; }
    public double max { get; set; }
    public double mean { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public string subdeviceGuid { get; set; }
    public string componentId { get; set; }
    public Dictionary<string, Entry> entries { get; set; }
}
```

Also, your JSON starts with '[' indicating that it's not a single object, but an array. So when you deserialize it, you should deserialize into an array of `Root` rather than a single instance, like this

```
Root[] myDeserializedClass = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root[]>(myJsonResponse);
```